# How to implement manual or automatic API subscription within API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Out-of-the-box functionality of the API Manager during API subscription (within API Store) is automatic. Manual subscription approval can also be implemented and this is nicely described.

However how do I manage to define this on API level?
So I want to be able to define for each API if the subscription can be approved automatically or manually?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment WSO2 API Manager doesn't capture such information at the API level to define whether subscription approval is automatic or manual.

Comment: Hello Lakmali, 
Thx for your answer!
Do you have an alternative? A workaround?